# Would it be more appropriate to have this code in an on click listener?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

This is the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started to initiate facebook login. (All inside the main activity, specifically in oncreate in the main activity)

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // start Facebook Login
  Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    }
  });
}
```

My question is would it be a valid to call the openActiveSession inside an onclicklistener for the loginbutton. It doesn't make sense to me to start the facebook login process exactly when the activity is initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is valid to  to call the openActiveSession inside an onclicklistener for the loginbutton but I give you a better way for this. it is below 
use this code in buttonClick event.

Because if you will call openActiveSession than it will open open facebook login dialog each time. but, if we want to check that user is already logged in than use the following method.

```
private void onClickFbLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    String[] permissions = { "email", "friends_birthday",
            "friends_location", "offline_access", "publish_stream",
            "user_photos", "publish_checkins", "photo_upload",
            "read_stream" };
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(
                statusCallback).setPermissions(permissions));

    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: i read the docs too but why do you test !session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()?

Comment: is this method inside the onclicklistener, thought it had to be public for that to be so?